# Fibonnaci Sequence

Tags: java

As a beginner in Java programming I was looking up some Java code. I found this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class FibonacciSeries {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the value of the number upto which the sequence should continue: ");
   int n = s.nextInt();
   fibonacci(n);
}

public static void fibonacci(int n) {
   if (n == 0) {
       System.out.println("0");
   } else if (n == 1) {
       System.out.println("0 1");
   } else {
       System.out.print("0 1 ");
       int a = 0;
       int b = 1;
       for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
           int nextNumber = a + b;
           System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");
           a = b;
           b = nextNumber;
       }
   }
}
}
```

Can anybody kindly tell me what exactly is going on after `public static void fibonacci(int n)`?

Comment: Can you kindly tell us your current understanding, to help us pinpoint where you are stuck?

Comment: Do you understand how to generate the fibonacci series (i.e. could you do it with a pen and paper)? If not, start there. If you do, see Sheepy's comment.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, you're correct.  You caught me.  I have to confess that I read the code enough to see what I interpreted as a stopping condition and assumed "beginner" would be confused by recursion.  I never read the loop until you pointed it out.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see here is a implementation of the [algorithm that calculates fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) up to a given amount of numbers `n`, plus the number `0`.

> the first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are either 1 and 1, or 0 and 1, depending on the chosen starting point of the sequence, and each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two.

As per definition, those number sequence starts with `0` and `1` in your algorithm.

---

```
if (n == 0) {
    System.out.println("0");
} else if (n == 1) {
    System.out.println("0 1");
}
```

These two statements handle the possibility, that the user enters a `0` or a `1` as limitation, and prints `0` or `0 1` respectively. (Thats what `System.out.println();` is for).

The third case (if the input is neither `0` nor `1`) calculates longer sequences:

```
else {
   System.out.print("0 1 ");                 //this statement prints the start "0 1 "
   int a = 0;                                //the two starting numbers a and b are initialized
   int b = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {             //for the given amount of numbers:
       int nextNumber = a + b;               //calculate the next number as sum of both previous numbers
       System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");   //print this number
       a = b;                                //set the old b as new a
       b = nextNumber;                       //set the new number as b
   }                                         //repeat
}
```

So for a sample input of `6`, the `else` case is entered, printing
`0 1`
after that, the for-each loop will run 5 times, printing:
`1`,`2`,`3`,`5`,`8`

Which are the first `n` + 1 fibonacci numbers.

---

Have a read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) on how the `for` statement works, to better understand whats going on, but basically it says:

```
for("start here"; "repeat as long as this condition is true"; "after each step do this")
{
    //Everything between the brackets will be executed once for every run through the loop.
}
```

Let us have a look at how the values will change with each iteration when the sample will be calculated:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ i ║ a ║ b ║ nextNumber ║ new a ║ new b ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║          1 ║     1 ║     1 ║
║ 2 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║          2 ║     1 ║     2 ║
║ 3 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║          3 ║     2 ║     3 ║
║ 4 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║          5 ║     3 ║     5 ║
║ 5 ║ 3 ║ 5 ║          8 ║     5 ║     8 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Little bit of theory: **[Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)**

```
    if (n == 0) {                     //if user insert 0 than print to console 0
        System.out.println("0");      
    } else if (n == 1) {              //if user insert 1 than print to console 0 1
        System.out.println("0 1");    
    }

    else {                            //for every other cases (2, 3,... x)
       System.out.print("0 1 ");      //print to console 0 1        
       int a = 0;                      
       int b = 1;                     //before cycle prepare two values 0 and 1         
       for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {             //Cycle since i which starts on 1 passed condition "is lover than inserted value"
           int nextNumber = a + b;               //store value of 0 + 1 
           System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");   //print this stored value
           a = b;                                //Set value in b into to variable a
           b = nextNumber;                       //set stored value as b
       }                                         //Increment i plus 1 and repeat cycle
    }
```

So at the end you will have if user insert 5. print **0** **1** and from cycle (0+1)**1** (1+1)**2** (1+2)**3** end of cycle end of method go back to main. for 5 printed 0 1 1 2 3. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Anothe way to define the fibonacci sequence. I think it's more clear.

```
public static void fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
    }

}
```